# How to solve python string format?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I wrote the below code for a simple math. As I know it should work perfectly. But I'm getting an error with the string format. The shell showing a message that "NameError: name 'guess' is not defined". But the variable is already defined there though.

```
import random
import re

#select a random number
myNumber = random.randint(1, 20)


#loop for the game
while True:
    try:
        guess = int(input("Guess a number and put here : "))
    except ValueError:
        print("not a number {}".format(guess))
    else:
        if not guess in range(1, 20):
            print('Put only number between 1 - 20')
            continue
        elif guess == myNumber:
            print("that's right")
            break
        else: 
            print("Bummer!")
```

Comment: If the user enters something that's not a number, `int()` will throw an exception instead of returning a value, and therefore `guess` is not defined when you try to print its value in the `except` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`guess` will only be defined if no error is raised in the `try` clause. Thus, when an error *is* raised, `guess` will never be defined, and Python will raise a `NameError`. You need to give `guess` a default value before the `try/except` block. Or, as @John Gordon has mentioned, you can get the user input outside of the for loop, and only attempt to redefine as an integer inside of the `try` clause.

Comment: Or retain the original string input as a separate value, and print _that_ in the except message.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, that would also work. And that would perhaps be a better option if the OP doesn't want to predefine `guess` as an integer.